# Sign out different user

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to be able to sign out some user that is logged in. By this I do not mean current user but some other user.

I, as an administrator, can deactivate or ban a user. At this point I would like to get this user and sign him out so when he makes his next request he gets redirected to log in page. After login attempt he would get a message why he cannot log in.

I am aware I can do it by writing my own authorization filter and go and fetch user from database each time but I would, if possible, like to avoid that.

Setting up authentication as follows hits mz OnValidatePrincipal each time a request is made but I do not know how to update exactly this user.

```
services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication")
    .AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", options => {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = new Func<CookieValidatePrincipalContext, Task>(async (a) => 
            {
                var expired = a.Principal.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Expired);
                if(expired != null && bool.Parse(expired.Value))
                {
                    a.RejectPrincipal();
                    return;
                }
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            })
        };
    });
```

I am also aware that I could write my own middleware and keep some kind of list of all the users that have logged in. That list could than be easily updated by an administrator and checked by the previous event.

What I would like to know is, can I get an instance of other logged user and can I than alter its claims?